# How to setup uWSGI Fast Router

Tags: python, uwsgi

Basically I have followed uWSGI official docs, tutorials. But I have not been able to make it work.

**Expectation**
The worker must handle a specific domain, e.g. api.countdown.localhost.

**My problem**

1. The worker does NOT receive any request.
2. The router says: "no python application found"

I guess I have done something fundamentally wrong.

**router.yaml**

```
uwsgi:
  plugins: fastrouter
  http: 0.0.0.0:8080

  master: true

  fastrouter: 127.0.0.1:1717
  fastrouter-subscription-server: 127.0.0.1:2626

  fastrouter-cheap: true
  logformat: %(addr) - %(user) [%(ltime)] "%(method) %(uri) %(proto)" %(status) %(size) "%(referer)"
```

**api.yaml**

```
uwsgi:
  base: /Users/khanhhua/project/src/console
  home: %(base)/venv
  pythonpath: %(base)

  socket: %(base)/tmp/sockets/%n.sock

  callable: application
  module: api.app

  subscribe2: server=127.0.0.1:2626,key=api.countdown.localhost:8080

  logformat: [API] %(addr) - %(user) [%(ltime)] "%(method) %(uri) %(proto)" %(status) %(size) "%(referer)"
```